# character gets stuck walking

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Sometimes my character gets stuck while walking. I've made this GIF to show what I mean:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Q8hH.jpg

I've checked all the floor elements to see if some were higher than the others but they are all on the same line

[image: .]

The only thing I've noticed is that it doesn't seem to stuck as much if I increase the movement speed.

Any ideas of why he gets stuck at random positions on the floor?

Comment: Please use the right tags. `unity != unity3d`

Comment: It's hard for us to help you if you don't show us everything you've got. Maybe show us your colliders?

Comment: How do you move the character? How do you handle collisions? We need to see some code.

Answer (score 0):

Some information are missing in your question, I had a problem looking like this. If you try to assign physics material to your floor it would probably solve it. '

Except if you are using 2d box colliders and you are placing them close to each others. If this is the problem you would I have to set a single box collider.